# Best route for adding conversations to messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have a inbox system but I am not sure how to implement a reply to feature. All messages should belong to some other entity, e.g. a "conversation".  When the first message is created, the conversation is also created.  All subsequent messages are then part of that conversation. Conversations can only occur between two users, there are no options to allow people to forward messages, or add more people to the conversation. If the users exchange several messages back and forth using the 'reply' action..the users should be able to view their past messages from that conversation in the view. What would be the requirements for doing this? Should I create a conversation model or can I add a new column to the Messages table `conversation_id`. If a user replies to message id 27, then it would create a new message id 28 and the `conversation_id` value would be 27. Then I can just do a desc from `conversation_id` 27. That will show the history of all messages that belong to id 27.

Answer (score 0):

You want to populate a `recipient_id` on the new `Message` in your `new` action? Is that right?

If a conversation is guaranteed to only have two users, you could do something like

`current_conversation.users.select { |u| u.id != current_user.id }`

or

`User.joins(:conversations).where("conversations.id = ? AND users.id != ?", current_conversation.id, current_user.id).first`

You're using the phrase "reply to", so I'm assuming the conversation already exists. If it doesn't, the author has to specify the other user in the conversation anyway.

Comment: If you think otherwise please just explain it more to me because from what I am reading it wouldn't be a functional reply to previous message. Remember in the reply to message view I would be showing threaded history of the conversation (just like all inbox messaging systems). Also you're correct that the conversation will always only have two users.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [Mailboxer Gem's sourcecode](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer), you might find some of your answers in there.